# Sorting a map[string][]struct{}

Tags: sorting, dictionary, struct, go

I would likde to sort this map by **cost**

```
type Graph struct {
    vertice string
    cost    float64
}

var graph map[string][]Graph
```

In the order of lowest to highest

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what "sorting a map" would mean. What are you trying to do afterwards? Maps are orderless, so they're not sortable in the traditional sense.

Comment: The [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) has multiple examples. Do you have a question about using Sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to sort each slice in `graph` by cost, you only need to implement [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) on `[]Graph`, then use a for loop to loop through the values.

```
type ByCost []Graph

func (gs *ByCost) Len() int { return len(gs) }
func (gs *ByCost) Less(i, j int) bool { return gs[i].cost < gs[j].cost }
func (gs *ByCost) Swap(i, j int) { gs[i], gs[j] = gs[j], gs[i] }

for _, v := range graph {
    sort.Sort(ByCost(v))
```

If you're trying to iterate through the map in sorted order by the *sum* of the costs in the `[]Graph`, that's going to be much less clean.

```
type GraphKeyPairs struct {
    key string
    value []Graph
}

// Build a slice to store our map values
sortedGraph := make([]GraphKeyPairs, 0, len(graph))
for k,v := range graph {
    // O(n)
    gkp := GraphKeyPairs{key: k, value: v}
    sortedGraph = append(sortedGraph, gkp)
}

type BySummedCost []GraphKeyPairs

func (gkp *BySummedCost) Len() int { return len(gkp) }
func (gkp *BySummedCost) Swap(i, j int) { gkp[i], gkp[j] = gkp[j], gkp[i] }

func (gkp *BySummedCost) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // O(2n)
    iCost, jCost := 0, 0
    for _, v := range gkp[i].value {
        iCost += v.cost
    }
    for _, v := range gkp[j].value {
        jCost += v.cost
    }
    return iCost < jCost
}

sort.Sort(BySummedCost(sortedGraph))
```